# Search partial full_name with Ransack where first_name and last_name are database columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

None of the 5 examples given in the [Ransack wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers#5-search-on-a-concatenated-full-name-from-first_name-and-last_name-several-examples) actually provide a proper thorough search on full name with a single input field if you have two columns in your database as `first_name` and `last_name`.

In `user.rb` I have:

```
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
      parent.table[:first_name], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')
    ),
    parent.table[:last_name]
  )
end
```

And the search form as follows:

```
= f.search_field :full_name_cont
```

In the database is a user with **first_name:** `Benjamin` and **last_name:** `Zobrist`.

**Example 1 (works):** If you search for `Benjamin Z` the code snippets will pull up the record as expected

**Example 2 (doesn't work):** If you search for `Ben Zobrist` it doesn't pull up the record.

How can I get example 2 working?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for full text search with fuzzy matching over multiple columns. I'm not sure there's an easy way around this.

You could have another (calculated) column with the value of full name which can be used for searching like you're describing even utilizing full text capabilities of your database. You could also use SQL view and perform searches against it. If even that's not yielding the results you'll probably have to go with a full-blown search solution like Elasticsearch, Solr, ...

Comment: can you point me in the direction of an example of searching using a view. I'm trying to get this exact thing working at the moment and ransack/rails is being painful.

Comment: In short - you create another column (eg. full_name) and create a postgresql trigger to keep the column up to date or you can create an before_save action to store the value of first_name + last_name in the full_name column. Then, using ransack, you query the full_name column instead of first and last name separately.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help.